# Automatically activating python virtual environments with pyvenv

Tags: python, doom

I am using [pyvenv](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/pyvenv) with [doom](https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs) and am trying to have my python virtual environments automatically loaded when I enter a certain project.

I saw [this relevant issue](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/pyvenv/issues/51) on pyvenv and have added the following code to my `config.el`

```
;; autoload python virtual environments
;; https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/pyvenv/issues/51#issuecomment-474785730
(defun pyvenv-autoload ()
  "Activates pyvenv version if .venv directory exists."
  (f-traverse-upwards
   (lambda (path)
     (let ((venv-path (f-expand ".venv" path)))
       (if (f-exists? venv-path)
           (progn
             (pyvenv-workon venv-path))
         t)))))
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'pyvenv-autoload)
```

I expect that whenever I enter a python file inside a project with a .venv directory, it would automatically activate the appropriate virtual environment. However, running `M-x shell-command` RET `which python` returns `/usr/bin/python` when I would expect it to return something like `/home/jacob/src/beets/.venv/bin/python`

**Some debugging:**

`python-mode-hook`'s value is

```
(er/add-python-mode-expansions
 doom--setq-tab-width-for-python-mode-h
 +python-use-correct-flycheck-executables-h
 evil-collection-python-set-evil-shift-width
 doom-modeline-env-setup-python
 pyvenv-autoload
 pipenv-mode)
```

Which looks good to me.

However,
`pyvenv-workon`'s value is `nil` which could be the issue.

Activating and deactivating the virtual environment through `pyvenv-activate` and `pyvenv-deactivate` works as normal. If I use this method, `which python` returns the expected `/home/jacob/src/beets/.venv/bin/python`

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? It's the first thing I'm looking for now I have to learn some python.

Comment: If you use poetry, which I've been using mostly lately, [poetry.el has a tracking mode](https://github.com/galaunay/poetry.el#tracking-poetry-virtualenv) that works well for automatically switching virtual environments in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that using **'projectile-after-switch-project-hook** with the following function works well. The downside is that you do have to add conditional statements to the `autoload-venv` function as you add new projects and virtual environments. The upside is that you don't need to have a completely consistent approach to storing and naming virtual environments, i.e. you could have some in your home directory and others in the project itself.

```
(defun autoload-venv()
(cond
 ((string= (projectile-project-name) "project_one")
        (pyvenv-activate "~/.virtualenvs/proj1_venv"))
 ((string= (projectile-project-name) "project_two")
        (pyvenv-activate "~/project_two/proj2_venv"))))

(add-hook 'projectile-after-switch-project-hook #'autoload-venv)
```